# Teleopt a Turtlebot 3 and controling arduino compatible LED-Matrix at the same time

Tags: turtlebot, arduino, ros-noetic

for a Uni Project I'm currently using a turtlebot 3 and through ROS noetic controlling its speed and angle via a Phyton controller. I want to control as well an Arduino compatible LED Matrix that I have. Any of you have somehow an idea to reach this. We are starters with ROS and are real noobs.
Thank u in advande

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.